# merging develop to release branch

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Maybe an easy question for the more experienced in git to answer but i am struggling for some hours now on this.

I have three branches: **Develop, MyBranch & Release.**

MyBranch extends Develop and since it was a longer feature, Develop was merged into MyBranch again two times. Release is branched off Develop and Develop is ahead of Release (since we still continue to work on features for the next release).

Now i have to merge MyBranch to Develop and to Release. The Merge to Develop didn't have any problems, but i wasn't sure about the merge to Release. Since develop was merged into MyBranch two times, i could by accident merge changes which are not wanted on release. What do i do? I thought about:

- Checkout new Branch MyBranchRelease
- Reverting the two merges from Dev into MyBranchRelease
- Merging Release into MyBranchRelease to solve conflicts
- Merge MyBranchRelease into Release

Does this make sense? Hope to hear from you guys

Comment: Each release will have a separate release branch like r1, r2 and so on.
So why do you want to merge your branch into an existing release branch ?
You should be branching off develop (after merging all the relevant changes needed for that particular release)

Comment: since the release branch has to be stable, we don't want all changes made on develop also on release. only selected & tested changes like MyBranch get merged into both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have:

```
          r--r--r (release)
         /
--d--d--d---d--d--d--d--d (Develop)
         \   \     \
          \   v     v
          mb--mb----mb--mb--mb--mb--mb
```

> Since develop was merged into MyBranch two times, I could by accident merge changes which are not wanted on release.

Creating a test branch as you describe is a good tactic except it involves [reverting merges](https://mijingo.com/blog/reverting-a-git-merge)

Another approach would be to create MyBranchRelease where MyBranch is, then rebase it on top of release, while dropping the two merge commits.

```
git checkout MyBranch 
git checkout -b MyBranchRelease 
git rebase -i release
```

Comment: thank you for assuring me on this. Just to clarify the rebase: do i have to explicitely drop the two merges while rebasing, or is this done implicitely? (since rebase takes the root of MyBranch and sets it on Release)

Comment: @JulianDm It should be done automatically, but double-check it.